# How to replace first occurance a character in string android

Tags: java, android

In android how do I replace the first occurrence of a character in a string 
with another? F

or example I want to replace first occurrence of character **v** 
in **vivu** with **/** so that output has to be **/ivu**

I found we can replace all occurrence of string with a character by `replace()` as follows:-

```
EditText n1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
String s1= n1.getText().toString();
s1=s1.replace(s1.charAt(i),'\')
```

But I don't want to change all occurences, just the first one

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1= n1.getText().toString();
String output = s1.replaceFirst("\","");
```